# How to pass value from html to typescript while value getting from for loop

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I'm developing Hybrid app using ionic 2. i am stuck in pass value from html to typescript. in this page i have first set select option from ion-select and i have set for loop(ngFor) in ion-option. below select option i have put button for add selected service to database(button is outside of ngFor so i can't send option id to typescript) and i had set option name in value.

> my code is below

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Service type</ion-label>
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="serviceName" >
    <ion-option value="{{x.name}}" *ngFor="let x of servicelist">{{x.name}}</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>

<button ion-button (click)="addService()"> Add service</button>
```

[image]

Comment: can you make it clearer? like what should happen exactly, what do you want to pass?

Comment: in addService(), you could just get by this: this.serviceName.id

Comment: `(click)="addService(serviceName)"` ? Otherwise why would you use a `[(ngModel)]` ?

Comment: i want to pass x.name and x.id on click "Add service" button.

Comment: You should wrap the whole thing into a form and work with the form values when submitting using the button.

Comment: `<ion-option [value]="x" *ngFor="let x of servicelist">{{x.name}}</ion-option>`, and you can use `(click)="addService(serviceName)"` (which you can rename since it is now a full service, not only a name)

Comment: serviceName will have only name , not id.

Comment: <ion-option value="{{x.id}}" *ngFor="let x of servicelist">{{x.name}}</ion-option>

Comment: @Suresh Kumar Ariya. thanks for comment but i need x.name also in typescript.

Comment: You can convert object to string using JSON.stringify(). public constructor() {
  this.JSON = JSON;
} <ion-option value="JSON.stringify(x)" *ngFor="let x of servicelist">{{x.name}}</ion-option> .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do following:

```html
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Service type</ion-label>
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="selectedService" >
    <ion-option [value]="x" *ngFor="let x of servicelist">{{x.name}}</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>

<button ion-button (click)="addService(selectedService)"> Add service</button>
```

in button you can pass anything from **selectedService** object.